# Monodromy Theorem and homeomorpihsm

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If (A,f) is a smooth unlimited covering surface of X, f maps A onto X, and X is simply connected, then the Monodromy theorem implies f is a homeomorphism? I can't see this totally. Do you have any idea? Thank You!